# Restore pretrained tensorflow model

Tags: tensorflow, deep-learning, save, restore

I have some pretrained models saved using tensorflow. For each model, I have three files:

**I am running tensorflow 1.9.0 on Ubuntu 18.0.4**

`*.ckpt.meta, *.ckpt.index and *.ckpt.data-00000-of-00001`.
I write this code to restore the model:

```
path= 'path to the folder'
with tf.Session() as sess:
    new_saver = tf.train.import_meta_graph(path + 'mobilenet_v1_0.75_224.ckpt.meta')
    new_saver.restore(sess, path + 'mobilenet_v1_0.75_224.ckpt')
```

I get this error:
**KeyError: 'SSTableReaderV2'**

Comment: What have you tried? Also, have you seen [Tensorflow issue](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/issues/1564) - what version are you running, what OS and other relevant details?

Comment: @IanQuah, I am not using the same code as in this :  https://github.com/tensorflow/models/issues/1564  . I want just to restore the graph and use it to do inference.